# Медиа-запросы CSS3

Tags: css3, html5

Здравствуйте. Проблема в медиа-запросах. Я немного запутался. Укажите, где моя ошибка.
Иконка с "Обслуживание". На 1200px ширины экрана мне нужно, чтобы ширина этого блока была 46.1%, а когда экран становится меньше 992px, то нужно, чтобы ширина этого блока была уже 55.1%.
Сделал медиа-запросы, но блок остается 55.1%. В общем ниже код и скриншоты.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row our_services__box">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="box_services__delivery_icon box__border"></div>
            <p class="our_services__name">Доставка</p>
            <p class="our_services__des">Благодаря наличию товарных запасов на наших складах, мы гарантируем минимальные сроки доставки приобретенной или заказанной мебели.</p>
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="box_services__installation_icon box__border"></div>
        <p class="our_services__name">Сборка</p>
        <p class="our_services__des">Благодаря наличию товарных запасов на наших складах, а также эффективной схеме поставок.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="box_services__service_icon box__border"></div>
        <p class="our_services__name">Обслуживание</p>
        <p class="our_services__des">Благодаря эффективной схеме поставок, мы гарантируем минимальные сроки доставки приобретенной или заказанной мебели.</p>
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .box_services__service_icon {
        width: 46.1%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .box_services__service_icon {
        width: 55.1%;
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: порядок определения блоков в css измените

Comment: Спасибо! Затупил...

Comment: Зачем Вы используете размеры в процентах? Это не очень хороший стиль кода. Я раньше указывала в пикселях, теперь использую сетку бутстрап и не парюсь

Comment: @Наталья, откуда информация, что это "плохой стиль"? Обычный "резиновый стиль" ... можно подумать используя сетку бутстрапа вы не используете этот "плохой стиль" ... так же используете, только при этом добавляете ещё кучу другого "плохого стиля", что имеется в бутстрапе.

Comment: @MedvedevDev никто не запрещает пользоваться резиновой версткой, Вы можете даже не использовать CSS вообще. Но есть определенные тенденции в сообществе, к которым иногда нужно прислушиваться. Это во-первых. Во-вторых, бутстрап позволяет выполнять те же операции в разы быстрее, что увеличивает производительность. В-третьих, возможно, человек не вникал в бутстрап и не знает, какие возможности он дает, и был бы рад его использовать...

Comment: @Наталья, в том то и дело, что "тенденции в сообществе" говорят об обратном. Интерфейсы сейчас становятся все сложнее, все больше нестандартных элементов. Бутстрап это просто набор готовых решений, а не замена css'у, это как полуфабрикаты - если идешь домой голодный, то можно и доширак купить, но дорогих гостей дошираком кормить не стоит (ну хотя бы сосисочек туда накроши). Я бы понял, если бы тут шел спор между скажем бутстрапом и фаундейшен, но вы предлагаете не использовать просто стили, а использовать наборы элементов из бутстрапа, это звучит довольно нелепо.